# Can compilers break control dependencies used for LoadStore memory ordering or similar, in any real use-cases?

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, cpu-architecture, memory-barriers

I'm reading the mail list about [LKMM: Add volatile_if()](https://lwn.net/ml/linux-kernel/YLn8dzbNwvqrqqp5@hirez.programming.kicks-ass.net/). The control dependency is somewhat subtle since it is easily forgotten by us developers.  So I wonder is there any real case that is caused by control dependencies?

In fact, I found some people argue that control dependency **cannot** manifest in real code. Any help?

Comment: [This](https://lwn.net/Articles/860037/) links the thread in your answer and gives a more easy understanding. I realize it's not what you are asking though. The issue highlighted in your question arises every time both branches of an `if` contain a store to the same location and you want these stores to be ordered with a load used in the `if` condition itself. The compiler may notice this and hoist the store out of the `if`. This is not very common but may happen in real code due to macro expansion or just because the programmer wanted the store repeated to easily change one branch later.

Comment: Oops, I just finished reading the link I posted before. Thinking about it, the point is that for the lifting to occur the value must not depend (data or address dependency) on any instruction on each branch. So it should be safe to hoist it anyway.

Comment: Yeah, in fact, I am still wondering why a lot of developers are still worried about it.

Comment: https://lwn.net/Articles/793253/ has some plausible examples of problems caused by compiler optimizations. But in terms of control dependencies, if you write code like `if (x) tmp=y;` that compiles to branchy asm, the CPU can read `y` before `x`.  But `arr[x]` is dependency-ordered after the read of `x` on a CPU with data-dependency ordering (i.e. non-Alpha).  ISO C doesn't guarantee that without `memory_order_consume`, so in practice you have to be careful not to give the compiler a way to break data deps, like `if(x == 0) tmp=arr[x]` can optimize to `if(x==0) tmp=arr[0]` with only a ctrl dep

Comment: @MargaretBloom: The linked patch suggests a use-case like `volatile_if(READ_ONCE(A)) 
 WRITE_ONCE(B, 1);` to give LoadStore ordering because speculative execution of stores can't make them visible to other threads. (The branch instruction has a data dependency on the load).  I don't think it's plausible for a compiler to optimize away a branch on `A` here, only if you did something like `tmp = READ_ONCE(A)` / `if( tmp ^ tmp == 0 ) WRITE_ONCE` or other always-true condition, or less trivially some other thing that a compiler could prove something about.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the situation is:

a) C was designed without much/any support for memory ordering.

b) Linux developers wanted to improve performance in ways that C doesn't support

c) Linux developers constructed their own inner language from macros, non-standardized inline assembly and "implementation defined by one compiler" behavior. Let's call this the "Not C Language".

d) Linux developers found out that their "Not C Language" has corner-cases that don't comply with the intentions of their "Not C Language".

> So I wonder is there any real case that is caused by control dependencies?

For programs written in C there can't be any real case where problems are caused by control dependencies; simply because you must rely on something that's guaranteed by C (e.g. proper locks) in the absence of memory ordering guarantees.

For programs written in the current version of their "Not C Language" there are theoretical cases where it is a problem ([example](https://lwn.net/ml/linux-kernel/CAHk-=whDrTbYT6Y=9+XUuSd5EAHWtB9NBUvQLMFxooHjxtzEGA@mail.gmail.com/#t)); which is why they're adding `volatile_if()` to the "standard that doesn't exist" for their "Not C Language". According to Linus ([here](https://lwn.net/ml/linux-kernel/CAHk-=whDrTbYT6Y=9+XUuSd5EAHWtB9NBUvQLMFxooHjxtzEGA@mail.gmail.com/)) there currently aren't any real cases of this happening in the Linux source code; and because nothing else in the world uses their "Not C Language" we can say that there currently aren't any real cases in the world.